# Как правильно сверстать заголовок?

Tags: html, css

В данный момент у меня получилось сделать с двумя разными span. Можно ли сверстать такой заголовок и сделать чтобы перенос строк делался автоматически, а не как у меня сейчас через span?

Мои искодники с codepen.io/WoodRest/project/editor/XwoLJB

```css
/**
 * index.scss
 * - Add any styles you want here!
 */
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.tape-title {
  display: table;
}

.tape-title:hover .tape-title-tx span {
  color: #fff;
}

.tape-title-tx span {
  display: table;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 6px 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.tape-title-tx span:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 53px solid #ddd;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: 0;
}

.tape-title-tx span:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 53px solid #ddd;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
}

.tape-title-top-vr {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: table;
  transform: rotate(-0.5deg);
  left: 14px;
}

.tape-title-top-vr:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  border-top: 35px solid #ddd;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My New Pen!</title>
  
  <!--  Styles  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.processed.css">
</head>
<body>
  
 <a href="#" class="tape-title">
   <div class="tape-title-tx">
     <span>
       <div class="tape-title-top-vr"></div>
       Длинный заголовок
     </span>
     <span>
       <div class="tape-title-top-vr"></div>
       в две строки
     </span>
   </div>
  </a>
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: я полагаю, что нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понял твою задумку, но у тебя используется слишком много элементов, для того чтобы сделать фон текста. Если это немного минимизировать, то получится текст, обернутый всего в один блок, тогда сделать перенос текста можно несколькими способами.
1. Текст перенесется сам если не будет хватать места в строке.
2. Принудительный перенос строки при помощи тега `<br>`.
3. Использование для родительского элемента свойств `display: inline-flex;` и `flex-direction: column;`, но в таком случае фон растягивается по размеру самой длинной строки.
4. Перенос текста при помощи свойства `white-space: pre-wrap;`, тут придется следить за  разметкой, чтобы не возникало лишних отступов за счет переноса строк.

```css
.link {
  display: inline-block;
}

.link:hover .text-wrapper {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration-color: #fff;
}

.link  + .link {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.link2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.link3 {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.text-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.text-wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 55px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  z-index: -1;
}

.text-wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: -1px;
  width: calc(100% - 7px);
  border-top: 6px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">
  <span class="text-wrapper">Длинный заголовок</span>
  <span class="text-wrapper">в две строки</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="link">
  <span class="text-wrapper">Длинный заголовок</span>
  <br>
  <span class="text-wrapper">в две строки</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="link link2">
  <span class="text-wrapper">Длинный заголовок</span>
  <span class="text-wrapper">в две строки</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="link link3"><span class="text-wrapper">Длинный заголовок</span>
  <span class="text-wrapper">в две строки</span>
</a>
```

Comment: У вас код гораздо приятнее, спасибо. Задумка в том, чтобы текст в span не заносить, но он переносился, если не влазит в ширину родителя.

Например: <a href="#">Текст в две строки</a> -  выглядеть это должно также как и в примерах у нас.

Comment: @WoodRest За счет обертки мы же создаем фон для текста, без нее можно сделать только общий фон для всего блока.